# itemTpl in List using icoMoon icons

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Here is my current temp

```
<div class="ProjectT">{strType}&nbsp - &nbsp{strTitle}</div>
```

I really dont know if it's possible via architect, but I want to replace {strType} by a switch case which would insert an IcoMoon icon depending on strType's value.

Icons is already added has it is supposed to (checked and it works)

Comment: I don't know about using Architect, but you could add a member function to your XTemplate, passing in `strType`, and do your `switch` statement in there.

Comment: Not quite sure to follow you there, and what about the icons?

Comment: Posted my response as an answer, to give better formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a CSS Class.
Wrap your {variable} in a  
Give the span the CSS class you created, and in the class define the font to be the Icomoon one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with IcoMoon, but you can probably adjust this to fit what you need for that:

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="ProjectT"><img src="{[this.getIcon(values.strType)]}" />&nbsp - &nbsp{strTitle}</div>',
    '</tpl>',
    {
        getIcon: function(strType){
            switch (strType)
            {
                case "x": return "x.png";
                //etc...
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Icomont are Fonts icons so this would not work. Plus i'm not quite sure that in the field where I write the html I can declare a new Ext.XTemplate since it's asking for html input :S